# Identify active GPU at a glance in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

My desktop PC is running Windows 7 on two GPUs (Intel onboard, Radeon card) both hooked up to a single monitor via a HDMI switch. (It's not a dual monitor setup, only one monitor is ever detected even though it's indirectly hooked up to two cards.)

This mostly works fine, I push the switch-button, Windows 7 goes ding-a-ling and it switched over to the other GPU. However there is no visual difference at all: in desktop both look exactly the same. Only when I try to start a game, I notice it was running off the wrong GPU, suddenly I'm in Intel Graphics lowres land and all the game settings are bonkers.

I know I can identify the active GPU by Right Click -> Screen Resolution -> Advanced Settings. It will show Adapter Type Intel graphics, or Radeon graphics, depending which mode is active currently. However I would like to be able to identify the active GPU at a single glance, without going into any menus.

Is there a way to get a visual feedback directly on the desktop level, like a different desktop background color (blue for Intel, red for Radeon), or a widget, tray icon, anything that displays the active GPU directly on the desktop?

I haven't found a way to create a visual difference that would apply to one GPU only but not the other. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Connect the display only to the Radaeon card instead of both? If the screen it black you'd know it's running on the Intel card. Maybe consider disabling the on-board chip or is there a specific reason it's enabled?

Comment: It's a dualboot system and the Intel is what I use in Linux. So I need both of them connected. It works too - just some visual feedback would be nice is all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, not an optimal solution, but I found two workarounds of sorts:

The Intel HD Graphics tray icon only shows when Intel HD Graphics is active. As a hint it will do, although it's a bit subtle and tray icons sometimes vanish / get pushed back for other reasons. A tray icon that switches between Intel / AMD would be better, and unfortunately the Radeon Settings icon doesn't vanish like the Intel one.

If you go through the Intel HD Graphics preferences, you'll find color management, and there an advanced tab that will let you change the hue (shift or invert colors, blue turns into green etc.). This change only applies to Intel graphics so it's very obvious. (Before I tried to play with other settings such as rotation but somehow that affected both GPUs)

The downside with the color change is of course that it affects ALL colors of everything, not just the desktop background or suchlike. So I'm still looking for a less drastic solution.